# SQL Server not listening on IP address even if TCP/IP is enabled

Tags: sql-server, database, tcp, connection, ip

I am trying to set up MS SQL Server Express 2019 to listen on TCP/IP and connect to it through IP address instead of shared memory. I am currently connecting through Windows Authentication and the SQL Server Management Studio (SMSS).

In the Configuration Manager, I have enabled TCP/IP and the desired IP address (192.168.0.198, port 1433). I have checked that "Listen All" is enabled, as is "Allow remote connections to this server" in SMSS. I also restarted the service after enabling TCP/IP.

[Image: Setting up the IP address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALN3v.png)

However, when I try to connect, it gives an error.

[Image: Error when connecting to server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6o793.png)

Is it required to set up an account, does Windows Authentication not work with IP address? I also could not ping or otherwise locate the server listening. In the Windows Resource Monitor, there is no service listening on 1433. What could be the reason for this?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you ping 192.168.0.198?  Does it resolve as expected?

Comment: Yes, it resolves. But there are many services listening on that address (according to netstat), SQL Server is not among them.

Comment: Can you connect locally, have you checked ports open on firewall if relevant

Comment: Your error says Cannot connect to 192.168.0.198, 1433 ..... if I try to connect to a non-existent SQL server on a false IP address, it doesn't have ", 1433" on the end of the error message for me.  Does that mean that you've actually typed "192.168.0.198, 1433" into the server name/address when trying to connect?  If so, you only need to type the IP address

Comment: Tried only typing IP address (I saw the port number being used in examples), but it doesn't connect. I will try enabling firewall as was suggested in another comment, maybe that is the issue.

Comment: Windows Authentication works fine with IP addresses - so long as the client machine and the SQL Server are on the same domain. So, you can't ping the server on that address? Is the desired IP address `192.168.0.198` one that's actually been allocated to the server? i.e.: was that IP address already in the field, or did you type it in yourself?

Comment: Have you restarted SQL Server since you enabled the TCP protocol and set the port number?   Grab the Error Log from SQL and check that it states after startup that it is listening on 192.168.0.198 on Port 1433

Answer (score 1):

if "Listen on all ips" is set to true/yes then it uses the port in the last entry on TCP/IP networking settings. IF you have 5 ips (localhost, public ip, etc) then you have to scroll down (might not be in view). There is a settings for "all ips" with a port number like 53477. You can either pick "NO" to listen to all ips option, change the port, or use the 53whatever port # listed to connect. check firewall settings too.

Answer (score 0):

On TCP/IP remove the 0(zero) in TCP Dynamic Ports.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the **TCP/IP** Protocol itself is **Enabled**